# cURL doesn't work through subprocess in Python 3

Tags: python, bash, macos, curl

I can successfully get Docker with the following command in a bash script: `curl -O  https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg > ./Docker.dmg`

Now I want to execute the same in Python:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["curl", "-O",  "https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg", ">", "./Docker.dmg"])
```

However, I am met with this error when running it:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  123M  100  123M    0     0  25.0M      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 27.2M
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: >
curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
```

It should be exactly the same bash script, but it doesn't work through the Python script. Should I add something more for it to work? Port?

Comment: Weird. I put the ">" inside with the ./"Docker.dmg" and it will work as intended, but still throw the error `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: >` ? Really strange. Python 3.6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this temporary solution helps you:

```
call(["curl -O https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg > ./Docker.dmg"], shell=True)
```

Here is [a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/7732200) how shell argument works.

UPDATE:

The thing is that for output redirection with `>` you need shell. To do this with subprocess, use `stdout` argument:

```
f = open('docker.dmg', 'w')
call(["curl", "-O",  "https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg"], stdout=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

[curl's man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-O) has this to say about the `-O` option:

> **-O, --remote-name**
>
> Write output to a local file named like the remote file we get. (Only the file part of the remote file is used, the path is cut off.)
>
> The file will be saved in the current working directory. If you want the file saved in a different directory, make sure you change the current working directory before invoking curl with this option.
>
> The remote file name to use for saving is extracted from the given URL, nothing else, and if it already exists it will be overwritten. [...]

As such, it's in fact `curl` itself what is writing your file, not Python, and there is no need at all to further redirect and read stdout. Your code can thus be simplified to just this:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["curl", "-O",  "https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg"])
```

This will download the `Docker.dmg` file and write it to the current directory. Note that it will overwrite an existing `Docker.dmg` file in the current directory if one exists already.